# Why do these li's not center?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, centering

I am trying to get these list items to center in the list, but I can't seem to figure out the problem. Here's the code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="centerDiv">
            <ul class="centerUL">
                <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#centerDiv {
    width: 330px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.centerUL {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 2px auto;
    line-height: 1.4;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't using a CSS Reset, you should. http://www.cssreset.com/

CSS Resets will normalise your elements so you know how they will act; what to expect from them.

By default, `ul`s and `ol`s will have a left-padding on them, for the bullets :)

http://jsfiddle.net/MXGz5/

```
.centerUL {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 2px auto;
    padding: 0; /* this new line */
    line-height: 1.4;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

... ixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use `text-align:center;` for the `ul` element and set `display:inline-block;` for the `li` elements.

```
ul{
text-align:center;
}
ul li{
display:inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MXGz5/1/)

Comment: This does not center the list items in the list - the `padding:0;` is needed, as mentioned above.